# I want to use the getUserMedia in Android Lollipop 5.0 WebView

Tags: android

I want to start a web camera using the getUserMedia in WebView of Android.
The following has written the code, but, errorCallback will have is called.
why not?

Incidentally, The following web site was implemented by reference to.

> [Android, WebViews, & getUserMedia: Putting it all together](http://www.flapjacksandcode.com/blog/2015/2/17/android-webviews-getusermedia-putting-it-all-together)

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

// Settings
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), “Android”);

// Set a web view client and a chrome client
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  // Need to accept permissions to use the camera and audio
  @Override
  public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, “onPermissionRequest”);
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals(LOCAL_FILE)) {
          request.grant(request.getResources());
        } 
        else {
            request.deny();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
// Load the local HTML file into the webview
myWebView.loadUrl(LOCAL_FILE);
```

[permissions]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

[JavaScript]

```
 var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
 var localStream = null;
 function init() {
    console.log(‘Getting user media with constraints’, constraints);
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMediaSuccess, handleUserMediaError);
 };

 function handleUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    console.log(‘[+] Successfully got local video stream!’);
    attachMediaStream = function(element, stream) {
          element.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    };
    attachMediaStream(document.getElementById(“localVideo”), stream);
 };

 function handleUserMediaError(error) {
    alert(‘[!] getUserMedia error: ‘, error);
 };

 window.onload = function() {
    init();
 };
```

Comment: Change the value of `LOCAL_FILE ` to reflect the web site that the `WebView` should grant access to (see answer below).

Answer (score 6):

i fixed the same  problem with this code

```
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });
```

Comment: It worked for me, now next issue is media stream is not binding on video element

Answer (score 0):

This was also failing for me following the same doc. The solution in my case: I needed to manually enable the permissions which the manifest was attempting to set. My device was not prompting me to accept them on installation.

On my Android device > Settings > Applications > Application Manager > MyAppName > Permissions > Turn on Camera & Microphone

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the value of the LOCAL_FILE to your full website URL. If you don't know exactly what format is expected, you can debug the output of `request.getOrigin().toString()` from the `run` method.

```
public void run() {
    if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals(LOCAL_FILE)) { // <-- HERE!
        request.grant(request.getResources());
    } 
    else {
        request.deny();
    }
  }
```